# Iterate only through objects

Tags: php, jquery, json

I am receiving some JSON from PHP like this (previewed in Firefox tools):

```
1:Object
  0:Object
  1:Object
  2:Object
  3:Object
  Name: "SomeName"
```

I now want to iterate through the objects, but not the Name key. It seems if I do an $.each it includes the key/value pair. How can I avoid it? Also why can I choose a numerical value for the first Object (I have it "1") but not assign a value to it? I wish it could look like this for example

```
1:SomeNameIGaveIt
  0:Object
  1:Object
  2:Object
  3:Object
```

That would make my Name k/v pair obsolete.

JSON

```
{"1": {"Name":"SomeName", "0":{"data":"data"}. "1":{"data":"data"}}}
```

Comment: Is that an array and the last value is a named key?

Comment: Can you post the actual JSON? This theoretical stuff is hard to diagnose.

Comment: I am going: array['id'] = array("Name"=>"SomeName"). Then I am using array_push(arrayOfObjects); to put in the objects.

Comment: @JonathanM Done. Basically I either need to tell jquery to avoid the Name key, or associate that k/v pair with the objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript, a String is a "subclass" of Object. Lucky for you, there's the typeof operator;

*in the Chrome console*

```
var a = "foo" //makes a String
var b = {}    //makes an empty Object
typeof a
"string"
typeof b
"object"
```

Using this, you can check to ensure something is not a string before doing an operation on it.

Other option: instead of iterating using the json $.each call, you could just iterate over it via a JavaScript for-loop. If you know the number of elements inside your SomeNameIGaveIt object is fixed, you could use a fixed number of iterations and then use the array indexing operator (SomeNameIGaveIt[index]), or use a for-in loop (for (var i in array){...})

If you use a for-in loop, you can check if the index is a number using typeof as mentioned above. Any of these approaches is going to yield pretty similar results, so pick whatever suits you best.

Comment: Thanks. Just to ask: Let's say I start off by getting a JSON response like this {"1":"Joey"}. Can it ever be appended to this: {"1":"Joey":{"age":"24"}} ie can an object be attached to that object?

Comment: @user3585210 -- No, that's invalid. How would access that inner object?

Comment: @user3585210 first, be careful: you're indexing by "1" instead of 1- the first is a string, the second is a number

. Second, no, but you can do this: 

x = {1:{name:'Joey', age:24}, 2:{name:'Jill', age:'32'}}